# Why do I need to forward declare class foo but not class bar, even though 'foo.h' and 'bar.h' are both included?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I was getting a C2143 error when trying to compile this code; I fixed it by forward declaring `class Level`, but I'm confused about why that's needed, since I already included `#include Level.h`, which is of course where `Level` is defined. What confuses me more, though, is that I *don't* seem to need to take the same measures for similar statements in the same place. Here's my code:

```
// global.h
// Global variables

#pragma once

#include "Level.h"
#include "view.h"
#include "ActorPlayer.h"

class Level; // Without this line C2143 (missing ; before *) is
             // generated after 'extern Level'

extern Level* gamelevel;
extern View* view;
extern bool gameover;
extern bool player_turn;
extern int game_ticks;
extern ActorPlayer* act_player;
```

My question is, why don't I also need a `class View;` and a `class ActorPlayer;`? What's the relevant difference?

In case it matters, here's Level.h:

```
// Level.h
// Header file for Level class

#pragma once
#include "Terrain.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "hex_math.h"

class Level
{
public:
    const int WIDTH;
    const int HEIGHT;

    Level();
    Level(int width, int height);
    Level(int radius);
    ~Level();

    bool isInBounds(OrdPair coord);

    int terrainAt(OrdPair coord);

    void update();

private:
    int** terrain;

    void init();

    void fillHex(int qCenter, int rCenter, int radius, int terrainID);

};
```

Comment: Because global.h includes level.h and vice versa. You have an include loop. Try to avoid those

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you've a circular dependency with include files:

```
global.h includes level.h
level.h includes global.h
```

What happens is

1. Compiler starts reading `level.h`
2. Reads `pragma once` that marks the file as already included
3. Finds inclusion of `global.h` and starts reading it (at that point)
4. Reads `pragma once` that marks the file as already included
5. Finds inclusion of `level.h` but ignores it (it was marked included in 2)
6. Keeps on reading the rest of `global.h` but the class `Level` is unknown

If the project is not trivial you should make a diagram of your classes and modules and decides what depends on (is built on) what. This diagram should be a DAG (without loops). More specifically it should be possible to subdivide the modules in "layers" in which no module from a lower layer depends on a module in an higher layer.

If you have a loop in your dependency diagram the project will be much harder to deal with (e.g. unit testing) because your modules are not really modules but the whole program becomes just a huge ball of code.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation of the why-for's; that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand. I'll try to fix the rest of my code so this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

In global.h you include Level.h, but then in Level.h you include global.h. The problem is very likely due to that circular dependency.

The idea of #pragma once is not really to prevent circular dependencies, but to prevent a file from being included twice.

It really depends on the compiler you are using whether #pragma once will work or not in your particular case.

The easiest solution is to avoid circular dependencies altogether.